# If I use twice a $.get() function with the same page will it load it twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm creating two codes that works with the same page with  two AJAX load in each code. Question is, I did both scripts separated and now I'm asking myself it this will make the browser will load twice the same page or it's smart and it will load the page once.

Thanks.

Comment: You would do well to provide your code and as a specific question.

Comment: If you call $.get twice, it will run twice ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. Calling `$.get` twice issues two AJAX requests. However the browser may get the response from a local cache depending on the server side (i.e. caching strategy set in HTTP headers). Assuming that that's what you are concerned about. But success handlers will still fire for each request.